# Particle Energy Correlation with Probability Cloud

Tags: particle-physics, wave-particle-duality, elementary-particles

Is there a relationship between a particle’s momentum/energy and it’s wavelength? I know the Planck Equation for photon energy, but does this also apply to Leptons, Quarks and other Bosons?

Answer (score 0):

For any elementary particle: $$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$ where $\lambda$ is the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave).

Does that answer your question? :)